# Bluetooth Low Energy scanner seems to work properly but find no devices

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a problem with Bluetooth Low Energy. Everything seems to be working fine.

Logger shows this: `onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=7 mClientIf=0`,which means that the status is success, clientif=6 refers to the client interface.

So the scanner is working properly. The problem is that it cannot find any device.

I have `BLUETOOTH, BLUETOOTH_ADMIN, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permissions in the manifest. I check for them when app starts. Everyone who has problem with "no scan results" gets the reply about enabling location. I did it and still nothing.

`onScanResults` never succeed.

I'm using android 7.0.0.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), AnkoLogger {

    lateinit var bleManager: BluetoothManager
    lateinit var bleAdapter: BluetoothAdapter
    lateinit var bleScanner: BluetoothLeScanner

    val REQUEST_BLUETOOTH = 0
    val REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION = 1

    val ui by lazy { MainUI() }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        ui.setContentView(this)

        checkLocationPerm()

        bleManager = getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
        bleAdapter = bleManager.adapter
        bleScanner = bleAdapter.bluetoothLeScanner

        checkEnableBluetooth()

        ui.scanButton.onClick {
            startScan()
        }
    }


    fun checkLocationPerm() {
        val perm = PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(applicationContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
        if (perm == PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            info("Location permission granted")
        } else requestEnableLocation()
    }

    fun requestEnableLocation() = requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION),
            REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION)

    fun checkEnableBluetooth() {
        if (!bleAdapter.isEnabled) {
            val enableBtIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_BLUETOOTH)
            info("Requested user to enable bluetooth.")
        }
    }

    fun startScan() {
        var scanResults = mutableMapOf<String?, BluetoothDevice?>()
        var bleScanCallback = BleScanCallback(scanResults)
        bleScanner.startScan(bleScanCallback)
    }


    class BleScanCallback(resultMap: MutableMap<String?, BluetoothDevice?>) : ScanCallback(), AnkoLogger {

        var resultOfScan = resultMap

        override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult?) {
            addScanResult(result)
            info("I found a ble device ${result?.device?.address}")

        }

        override fun onBatchScanResults(results: MutableList<ScanResult>?) {
            info("I found a device!")
        }

        override fun onScanFailed(errorCode: Int) {
            info("Bluetooth LE scan failed. Error code: $errorCode")
        }

        fun addScanResult(scanResult: ScanResult?) {
            val bleDevice = scanResult?.device
            val deviceAddress = bleDevice?.address
            resultOfScan.put(deviceAddress, bleDevice)
        }
    }
}
```

I just want to log the addresses of bluetooth devices. I check BleScanCallback object and it is fine. I have no idea what's wrong with my code.

Comment: If you use another BLE scanning app, like nRF Connect, do the devices show up there?

Comment: @Emil nRF Connect shows nothing. Dunno why. When I go to bluetooth setting on my phone and scan manually it detects my other two phones(both of them support BLE). And there's another thing, yesterday I was able to find one of this phone, but today my app doesn't detect them.

Comment: If you are sure there are advertising BLE devices nearby and it doesn't show up there either, then something is wrong with your phone/OS, either a bug or some setting is misconfigured.

Answer (score 0):

It's turned out that phones that do support Bluetooth Low Energy are not visible. When I simulted GATT server on one of then my app found this phone.